# creating a pandas dataframe iteratively

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy-ndarray

I have 703 tab seperated text files files of shape (X,4) where X can be any positive number with the largest value being 217632347. For example three of the files look like:

```
###File ID_739.txt
region   latitude    department      product
  NY        71           HR             -

###File ID_618.txt
region   latitude    department      product
  LA        91           R&D            -

###File ID_917.txt
region   latitude    department      product
  NY        71           HR
```

I want a dataframe (maybe pandas or numpy) which looks like:

```
region    latitude      ID_739     ID_618        ID_917
  NY         71            1           0            1
  LA         91            0           1            0
```

So in a way I am looking for one-hot encoding whereby I go put one under columns for which region and latitude is the same. For example ID_739 and ID_917 has the same region and latitude so they get a 1 and ID_618 gets a zero. I have 703 files which means my final dataframe will be of shape (X,705). It's 705 because each file becomes a column + region + latitude. How can I do that efficiently considering I have lots of lines in each text files? Insights will be appreciated.

Comment: can you check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68888909/16343464) also works for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create big DataFrame with column `New` by filenames, then aggregate `join`, so possible use `one-hot encoding` by [`Series.str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
import glob

files = glob.glob('files/*.txt')
dfs = [pd.read_csv(fp).assign(New=os.path.basename(fp).split('.')[0]) for fp in files]


df = (pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
        .groupby(['region','latitude'])['New']
        .agg('|'.join)
        .str.get_dummies()
        .reset_index())
print (df)
  region  latitude  ID_618  ID_739  ID_917
0     LA        91       1       0       0
1     NY        71       0       1       1
```

Comment: Can you briefly explain what you are doing in the last line?

Comment: @John - added some explanation

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you files are in the current directory, you can use `glob` to read your files and merge with the dummies obtained from the "latitude" column:

```
from glob import glob
files = glob('ID_*.txt')
df = pd.concat({f[:-4]: pd.read_csv(f, sep='\s+') for f in files}).droplevel(1)
(df[['region', 'latitude']].merge(pd.get_dummies(df['latitude']).T,
                                  left_on='latitude',
                                  right_index=True,
                                 )
                           .drop_duplicates('latitude')
)
```

output:

```
       region  latitude  ID_739  ID_917  ID_618
ID_739     NY        71       1       1       0
ID_618     LA        91       0       0       1
```

Comment: crosstab dont create `one-hot encoding`

Comment: @jezrael I don't understand your comment, this works for me

Comment: yes, becuase sample data. crostab is used for counts, not for `one-hot encoding`

Comment: @jezrael I had missed a point in the question, thanks. Should be fixed now